# C++ Polymorphism setting derived classes to base class object

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am working on a game using C++ with the SDL library, and am having troubles with polymorphism. My project includes a lot of code so I will try to use an example as best as I can.

I have a base class `Pawn` and derived classes `Knight` and `Mage`. `Pawn` includes functions that are used by `Knight` and `Mage`, but `Knight` and `Mage` have functions specific to themselves.

Lets say `Pawn` has a function `move()`, and `Knight` and `Mage` each have a function `attack()` that does different things for each of them. I have created an object `selectedPawn` in order to click between the `Knight` and `Mage` and select each of them.

```
Knight* knight = new Knight();
Mage* mage = new Mage();
Pawn* selectedPawn = new Pawn();

selectedPawn = knight;
selectedPawn->move(); //This does not give me any errors and runs as it should.
selectedPawn->attack(); //Error: class "Pawn" has no member "attack"
```

My question is, is there a way of making this possible? If not, am I totally missing the purpose of polymorphism or executing it in the wrong manner?

Comment: [Virtual functions](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/210/C++FAQ/virtual-functions.html).

Comment: Your pointers should be of the base type, not the derived type if `Knight`, `Mage` and `Pawn` are derived from the same parent class that contains virtual functions.

Comment: Do you mean make them something like `Pawn* Knight = new Knight()`?

Comment: @Dallas Don't they have a common base class?

Comment: "I have a base class Pawn and derived classes Knight and Mage." `Pawn` *is* the base class.

Comment: @Dallas You need to show us the class hierarchy.  If all of those classes are derived from the same base pointer, then polymorphism works by declaring the base pointer type, and then creating dynamically the desired object and assigning to the base type.  And you really should have named your base class something like `ChessPiece` or similar, not `Pawn`.

Comment: @FredLarson OK, I see. That doesn't make any sense. A `Knight` isn't a `Pawn` nor is a `Mage`.

Comment: If both `Knight` and `Mage` have the `attack()` method, why don't declare it in the base class `Pawn` as pure virtual? Are there any other subclasses of `Pawn` that cannot attack?

Answer (score 2):

Your base class defines your *interface*

```
struct Pawn
{
    virtual void move() = 0;
    virtual void attack(Pawn*) = 0;
    virtual ~Pawn() = default;
};
```

Your derived classes *implement* that interface, implementing their own specific details for each function

```
struct Knight : Pawn
{
    void move() override;
    void attack(Pawn*) override;
};

struct Mage : Pawn
{
    void move() override;
    void attack(Pawn*) override;
};
```

Now you can call those functions on a base class pointer, but because of *polymorphism*, the derived function will be called, and therefore the functionality specific to that derived instance

```
Pawn* piece1 = new Knight;
Pawn* piece2 = new Mage;

piece1->move(); // will call Knight::move
piece2->move(); // will call Mage::move
```

Where this becomes useful is you can have a function which takes a `Pawn` pointer, and it doesn't know if it's a `Knight` or `Mage`, but because of polymoprhism, the correct functions get called

```
void do_move(Pawn* piece)
{
    piece->move();
}

void do_attack(Pawn* aggressor, Pawn* piece)
{
    aggressor->attack(piece);
}

piece1->attack(piece2); // Knight attacks Mage
piece2->attack(piece1); // Mage attacks Knight
```

Comment: You forgot virtual destructor. Critical mistake!

Comment: @Dallas don't forget your virtual destructor in the base class, as pointed out by Ivan! Edited the answer to add it in

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in C++ (you can do this in some Smalltalk-derived languages)

What you probably want to do is create another class Attacker, with the Attack method as a pure virtual method.

Make Knight and Mage derive from Attacker as well as Pawn.

Use the dynamic_cast operator on selectedPawn to try and get an Attacker pointer from it.  If the Attacker* is non-null, you can use it to call attack() on the selectedPawn.

```
Attacker* attacker = dynamic_cast<Attacker*>(selectedPawn);
if (attacker) {
  attacker->attack();
}
```

Comment: "I have a base class Pawn and derived classes Knight and Mage." `Pawn` *is* the base class.

Comment: @Fred Larson - But Pawn does not have attack() method, and it sounds like he doesn't want to add it to Pawn().

Comment: If that's the case, this design defeats the purpose of polymorphism.  The program, or at least this part of the code, becomes no better than a big `switch` or `if` block, something that polymorphism is suppose to eliminate.